# LogAnalytics - Join VMProcess and Perf tables to find resource consuming PIDs?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azureportal, azure-vm

I am trying to find a way to join the [`Perf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/perf) table with the [`VMProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/vmprocess) table, but there doesn't seem to be anything in common that I can join on.

Basically, I would like to find high resource consuming PIDs. The product we develop uses the same service/executable name for each running instance, so in the `Perf` table I get `InstanceNames` like `Service#10`, `Service#24`, etc. In the `VMProcess` table, however, I can get much more granular and sort by `ExecutablePath` or `CommandLine` to determine which process is the culprit.

How can I join these two datasets? Or is there perhaps a better way to find process CPU utilization on Azure VM's? I do not want to run perfmon on each VM; I really need something from Log Analytics or Azure Monitor.

I know naming the executable or service uniquely would be a much better solution, but that is not something that the product team has prioritized so I need another way to sort out which PID is consuming the most CPU cycles.

[Find High CPU Processes in Azure Log Analytics](https://www.cloudsma.com/2018/07/cpu-processes-azure-log-analytics/) I thought was the answer, but it doesn't join on the VMProcess table so I still am a bit clueless on which process is consuming the most resources.

Comment: Can you add the perf and VM process query to the question so that i can answer more precisely.

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT - as noted in that linked article, there is a quite long query to get the performance.

https://pastebin.com/TtgYz0qY - Find Top processes utilizing CPU

Then there is a 'VMProcess' table - in Kusto / LogAnalytics you can see it here - ExecutablePath, CommandLine or Services seem to be the only columns I can definitively tell which process this actually is since we run a lot of processes with the same name, only difference is where the process is started from:
VMProcess
| project TimeGenerated, Computer, ExecutablePath, CommandLine, Services